# How to stop flash from overlapping popup content

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site and the popup windows are going under the flash banner. I've tested this in FF7 and Chromium. I have no idea how can I fix that. Here is the [link](http://www.broodds.com), I also attached an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpuC5.jpg). Any suggestion how can I fix this?

Comment: Where is this image you attached?

Comment: The system doesn't allow me to upload because of the reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `wmode=opaque` or `wmode=transparent` on the SWF. See http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15523.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Add [`wmode="opaque"`](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=e5141) to the params.

Comment: I added this parameter(<param name="wmode" value="opaque"> ) but I'm still getting this error